# $W_0^{m,p}(\Omega)$ is a proper closed subspace of $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory

$W_0^{m,p}(\Omega)$ is a proper closed subspace of $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$

how to prove this one what is function which is in $W^{m,p}(\Omega)$ and not in 
$W_0^{m,p}(\Omega)$

is $|x|$ will works?

Comment: $|x|$ does not in general have $L^p$-derivatives (for instance, in $1$-d, all its derivatives of order greater than 2 contain $\delta$-measures at $0$). If $\Omega$ is bounded, I would just suggest taking a constant function.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou..can you tell how to prove closed  ness

Comment: $W_0^{m,p}$ is, by definition, the closure of $C_0^{\infty}$ inside $W^{m,p}$, so it's closed by definition.